# Constraints like "max(column a + column b) == 2" are not DCP

Tags: python, convex-optimization, binary-variable, disciplined-convex-programming, cvxpy

I am struggling with the following constraint on a minimization problem

```
cvx.max(z[:, i] + z[:, j]) == 2
```

where `z` is a Boolean matrix decision variable. I need to ensure that at least one row in `z` has a $1$ in two given columns (`i` and `j`). CVXPY informs me that this is not DCP-compliant.

Can you think of a DCP formulation that would enable a constraint such as `z[k, i] == 1 and z[k, j] == 1` for at least one `k`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if it is DCP, but you can write it as a quadratic constraint:
$$\sum_k z_{k,i} z_{k,j} \ge 1$$
You can also linearize as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_k x_{k,i,j} &\ge 1 \\
x_{k,i,j} &\le z_{k,i} \\
x_{k,i,j} &\le z_{k,j}
\end{align}

Comment: The linearization is DCP-compliant (the quadratic constraint is not).